# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I'm trying to use date picker in a MERN tutorial, but it fails to compile because it can't resolve 'react-datepicker'.  I've rm -rf node_modules and datepicker to no avail.

component.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
```

I'm wondering if the version (2.10.0) I've installed is somehow not compatible with something... when I installed there were no err or missing required dependencies.

Comment: Have you checked in your node modules folder to see if that file is actually there? There's a Github post with that error, but it says that this issue was fixed in v2.9.3, and you're using a later version: https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1882

Comment: Yep, it's there.  Just realized I put the wrong v though, 6.12.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good grief.
'../react-datepicker';

Thanks for helping me rubber duck!

Answer (score 6):

I have resolved this problem
Type `npm install react-datepicker --save` in terminal on local environment or on production

Then import these in your component

`import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";` used this in component where i need date-picker

`import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";` used this app.js

it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

> import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker';

Use this.
The same problem occurred with my code too, and this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Go and check react-date-picker folder in node_modules.

Mine was not react-datepicker..

So importing should be;

```
import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";
import "react-date-picker/dist/DatePicker.css";
```

Answer (score 1):

Following [this suggestion](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1882#issuecomment-1257442620) to also install @types/react-datepicker fixed this issue in a TypeScript app I'm working on.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34465999)

Comment: I had same issue and only this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above code snippet worked for me.. But the below snippet worked fine in my react application.

https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/879

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker"
import "react-datepicker/src/stylesheets/datepicker.scss";

export default function SimpleClassDatePicker() {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

    return (
      <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
    );
};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can improve your answer by adding an explanation why this works (under what circumstances) and the other approaches don’t.

Answer (score 0):

"npm i react-date-picker" It works for me ."npm i react-date-picker"not "npm i react-datepicker"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The package in the question is `react-datepicker`, not `react-date-picker`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, everything worked in local, but when I deployed to heroku, I received the error `module not found`. After investigating, turned out `react-datepicker` was in devDependencies in package.json vs in dependencies.

Moved this and it solved my problem.